# Get $HOME and/or username in QML

Tags: qml

I need to know how to get the user name and/or home directory of the users. I've googled around for a while but can only find the variables for C++ or BASH.

How do I get the user name or home directory? I'm writing in QML.

Comment: Thanks for posting my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to get the Username in C++ and then exchange that data from C++ to qml.

Read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html) how to exchange data between qml and C++.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I don't know C++, nor am I interested in learning it.. I just dont get these header files, and then a seperate source file. ANd then to compile stuff. 

I'd be happy to get some help in this matter.

Comment: @DanielHolm qml might be easy to use and provide rapid development capability, but has its constraints. I would suggest you to learn C++ as well. May be just the basics. The combination, is DEADLY. Try reading this http://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113 or http://www.amazon.com/An-Introduction-Design-Patterns-Qt/dp/0131879057 if you want to go through the Qt way directly. Its not that difficult. Try, fall, come to the community, people will surely help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Amit. I will take a look. Also I've asked in the Ubuntu Touch mail list for some help until I'm able to make it myself. I'm currently studying political environmental science, that's my QML is so much easier to get going then C++ - at the moment. But, as I was sayin', I will take a look.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I implemented it:

**QmlEnvironmentVariable.h**

```cpp
#ifndef QMLENVIRONMENTVARIABLE_H
#define QMLENVIRONMENTVARIABLE_H

#include <QObject>

class QQmlEngine;
class QJSEngine;

class QmlEnvironmentVariable : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:    
   Q_INVOKABLE static QString value(const QString &name);
   Q_INVOKABLE static void setValue(const QString &name, const QString &value);
   Q_INVOKABLE static void unset(const QString &name);
};

// Define the singleton type provider function (callback).
QObject *qmlenvironmentvariable_singletontype_provider(QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *);

#endif // QMLENVIRONMENTVARIABLE_H
```

**QmlEnvironmentVariable.cpp**

```cpp
#include "QmlEnvironmentVariable.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

QString QmlEnvironmentVariable::value(const QString& name)
{
   return qgetenv(qPrintable(name));
}

void QmlEnvironmentVariable::setValue(const QString& name, const QString &value)
{
   qputenv(qPrintable(name), value.toLocal8Bit());
}

void QmlEnvironmentVariable::unset(const QString& name)
{
   qunsetenv(qPrintable(name));
}

QObject *qmlenvironmentvariable_singletontype_provider(QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *)
{
   return new QmlEnvironmentVariable();
}
```

Then in `main()` add a call to [qmlRegisterSingletonType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-2) (or in your re-implemented  [QQmlExtensionPlugin::registerTypes()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlextensionplugin.html#registerTypes) method if you're creating a plugin):

```cpp
#include "QmlEnvironmentVariable.h"
#include <QQmlEngine>
// ...
qmlRegisterSingletonType<QmlEnvironmentVariable>("MyModule", 1, 0,
    "EnvironmentVariable", qmlenvironmentvariable_singletontype_provider);
```

Finally, use it in QML like so:

```qml
import MyModule 1.0
Item {
  Component.onCompleted: console.log("My home directory: " + EnvironmentVariable.value("HOME"))
}
```

Comment: I don't know C++ so I can't figure you how to do the third step. I pasted it into main.cpp and I got:

 /home/collin/liri-dev/liri-player/src/main.cpp:12: error: 'qmlRegisterSingletonType' does not name a type
 qmlRegisterSingletonType<QmlEnvironmentVariable>("MyModule", 1, 0,
 ^

Comment: Whoops. I was missing an important part from that snippet: #include <QQmlEngine>

Answer (score 0):

My solution was like this:

1.) create `config.h` file with the `Config` class:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
#include <QStandardPaths>

class Config : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Config(QObject *parent = nullptr) {}

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getHome() {
        return QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation).first();
    }
};

#endif // CONFIG_H
```

2.) set the `setContextProperty(...)` in your `main.cpp`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    Config config;
    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("config", config);
}
```

Then you can simply call `config.getHome()` in your qml-js file.