# Calling OS Environment in QML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm trying to call the **OS environment variable** in **QML** and **JavaScrip**, but I can't find any solution.

what I usually do in python, I launch a command line and clarify a variable like so:

```
set MY_PATH="C:/ProjectB"
```

then in same command line I execute Python and call the variable like so:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ.get("MY_PATH")
C:/ProjectB
```

It works perfectly in Python case, but How can I achieve the same thing in QML or Javascript?

**Note**: I'm only limited to use these 2 languages and C++ is not supported.

**Edit**: The 3rd party application that I'm working on using QML to create custom interface and javascript to write plugins, **there is no compiler to compile the C++**, so I'm limited to use **QML** and **javascript** only, hope that clearify the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get $HOME and/or username in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408691/get-home-and-or-username-in-qml)

Comment: @folibis nope it's not duplicated and not helpful, the solution for that question is C++, but I'm limited to only use Js and QML.

Comment: There is no way to access system environment from QML only.

Comment: @folibis I see... how about access to the command line within QML or Javascript? I know Ajax can access to REST API, but I'm not sure if Ajax can access to any .bat file.

Comment: Ajax is just a term or technology of JavaScript. Due to security etc. JS is isolated from OS. Since QML based on JS it's on the same security level. So the only way to accomplish your task is using some external QML module. But it is worth considering that all build-it QML modules you use in "QML only" environment are written in C++ and they are somewhere on your target device. So you just need to compile a module on another machine and place it on the target one.

Comment: As a workaround you can pass all environments you need from command line and then dispatch it using [application.arguments](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop)

Comment: @folibis I check the application, yes, there is qml folder and all the packages are in .dll, correct me if i'm wrong, base on what I understood is that I need to write an extra qt plugin .dll that can access to OS variables or command line and add it to the application qml library and then I can access to it.

Comment: @folibis yes, the workaround worked perfectly, that was a quick and awesome solution.

Comment: @folibis can you make the command line arguments comment into an answer? IMO that is the best answer we are going to get

Answer (score 1):

The OP seems to be facing 2 issues:

1. reading an environment variable from pure QML
2. getting a system shell to invoke a subprocess from pure QML

I don't have any ideas for solving (2), but I found multiple decent approaches to solving (1).

To solve the issue of reading environment variables from QML, the two approaches I am aware of are based on: (a) leveraging the internal built-in code of the QML engine, which does process a designated small set of environment variables inside itself, and/or (b) using the `Qt.application` global QML variable to access `Qt.application.arguments`

For people like me who first develop their QML code using `qmlscene`, the good news is that both of the approaches work when launching under `qmlscene` as well as when launching a compiled Qt/QML application.

In cases where all you need is to use an environment variable as a simple boolean flag, then you can "hijack" one of the [built-in Qt Quick Environment Variables](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-environment.html) that are processed by the QML engine internals.

For example, if you do this before you launch the QML app:

```
export QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_ACCENT="#0B610B"
```

Then in your QML code you can detect it using the following expression:

```js
  import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
  // ....
  readonly property color sentinelColor: "#0B610B"
  visible: Material.accent == sentinelColor
```

In the preceding code snippet, `visible` will be set to `true` if the environment variable was exported as shown, and will be set to `false` otherwise.

Here is a link to a [full working sample QML application using this tactic](https://github.com/219-design/qt-qml-project-template-with-ci/pull/41).

---

Using `Qt.application.arguments` works similarly. When you launch the application, provide some flag argument at the command line:

```
./myapp -e
```

Or similarly when using qmlscene:

```
qmlscene -I ../../libstyles/imports/ -e main.qml
```

Then, in QML code:

```js
import QtQml 2.15
// .....
visible: Qt.application.arguments.includes('-e') // toggle visibility via CLI arg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a C++ solution for this, you only hope is requesting it to be implemented in your 3rd party app or in Qt directly.

There is no way to do it in QML currently.

Comment: alright, how about access to the command line and return the value of executed file? like Python or .bat?

Comment: I'm afraid it's the same

Answer (score 0):

If you can call Python script pass by `Qt.openUrlExternally(url target)`, may can get the env value. And then use `XMLHttpRequest` read text file. github: https://github.com/qyvlik/readenv4qml,

```
Qt.openUrlExternally('read_env_value_and_write_value_to_file.py');
readFileAsync('env_val.txt');
```

some code:

```
function setHeader(xhr, headers) {
    //"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    for(var iter in headers) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(iter, headers[iter]);
    }
}
function ajax(method, url, headers, data, callable) {
    headers = headers || {};
    callable = callable || function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        callable(xhr);
    };
    xhr.open(method, url);
    setHeader(xhr, headers);
    if("GET" === method) {
        xhr.send();
    } else {
        xhr.send(data);
    }
}
function readFileAsync(file, callable, error) {
    callable = callable || function(fileContent) {
        console.log("fileContent size: ", fileContent.length);
    }
    error = error || function(e) {
        console.log("readFileAsync error : ", e);
    }
    ajax("GET", file, {}, "", function(xhr){
        if(xhr.status !== 200) {
            error("file "+file + " not exist!");
        } else {
            callable(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

ref:

[qml-snippet](https://github.com/qyvlik/qml-snippet/blob/master/code/commont/commont.js)

Comment: when I use `Qt.openUrlExternally` to run a python file that to read `os.environ.get("MY_PATH")`, during execution it crashes!

Comment: I create repo in github, https://github.com/qyvlik/readenv4qml, you can try it in windows.